# Virtual Consoles in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tty, console

In [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) link is mentioned that Linux GUI is installed on *tty7*, but when I change my consoles using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> and check it by the command `tty`, I see that I have a GUI on my *tty1* and *tty2*.
I'd like to know:

- Why is in most sources mentioned that the GUI is on *tty7*?
- I have a GUI on my *tty1* and *tty2* on Ubuntu 20.04, *tty3-6* are consoles without GUI and *tty7* prints information about  `/dev/sda2`, is tty7 another console? If yes how does it differ from other consoles? If no, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Which tty's are configured for X11 or Wayland (the GUI) is up to the distribution being used, although a lot follow the '1-6 for getty processes' (which connect a tty to a login process), '7 for GUI' line.

Hardware limitations force some other solutions. I suspect you have one of those. Raspberry Pi?